# MapThread over a nested list

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax

This may be a simple question. Please close it if it is already answered.

I have a nested list

```
kr = {{35, 32, 27, 20}, {36, 33, 28, 21}, {37, 34, 29, 22}}
```

I want to use a function `flo[x_,y_,z_]` on each of the lists after modifying it. So the Mapthread on a given list `k0` (eg. {35, 32, 27, 20}) will look like this

```
MapThread[flo[L, ##] &, {Most@k0, Rest@k0}];
```

I want the output to look like this.

```
qfr = {{flo[L,35,32], flo[L,32,27],flo[L,27,20]},{flo[L,36,33], 
           flo[L,33,28],flo[L,28,21]},{flo[L,37,34], flo[L,34,29],flo[L,29,22]}}
```

I tried to do the following without much luck. what am I missing?

```
MapThread[flo[L, ##] &, {Most@#, Rest@#}] & kr
```

Comment: You're almost there... you just need to `Map` it on to `kr` like this: `MapThread[flo[L, ##] &, {Most@#, Rest@#}] & /@ kr`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about

```
flo[L, ##] & @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ kr
```

Regarding your initial try, this would work:

```
MapThread[flo[L, ##] &, {Most@#, Rest@#}] & /@ kr
```

Without the `/@` you are multiplying the expression `MapThread[flo[L, ##] &, {Most@#, Rest@#}] &` with every element in `kr`. The `/@` on the opposite uses the expression as a function and applies it to every element in `kr` treated as a list.